# How to map a viewModel to a hierarchy model with arrays with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, arrays, mapping, automapper, asp.net-mvc

A deep model is code-generated with lots of arrays (think WCF proxy genererated code based on a wsdl) that needs to be filled with a flattened viewmodel. There are no naming conventions between the 2 models.

The flat model looks for example like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

The deep model looks for example like this:

```
public class DeepLevel0
{
    public DeepLevel1 Level1 { get; set; }
}

public class DeepLevel1
{
    public string Prop1;
    public DeepLevel2[] Level2 { get; set; }
}

public class DeepLevel2
{
    public string Prop2;
    public string Prop3;
}
```

The end mapping result should be the following

```
DeepLevel0.Level1.Prop1 = ViewModel.Item1
DeepLevel0.Level1.Level2[0].Prop2 = ViewModel.Item2
DeepLevel0.Level1.Level2[0].Prop2 = null;
```

I really like the validation system in AutoMapper, knowing that you tackled all properties.

I got the following working (but loosing the validation):

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, DeepLevel0>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Level1, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => 
          new DeepLevel1 {
                            Prop1 = s.Item1,
                            Level2 = new[]
                                        {
                                            new DeepLevel2
                                                {
                                                    Prop2 = s.Item2,
                                                    Prop3 = null
                                                }
                                        }
                        }));
    }
```

Is there an other better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think so. You can always switch to using a constructor for the DeepLevel objects which might tidy them up a bit.